# « Non pas tant … mais surtout … » est-il correct ?

Tags: locutions, constructions

« Non pas tant … que … » ne me pose pas de problème, mais je me demande s'il est possible d'utiliser « Non pas tant … mais surtout … ».

Par exemple :

> Nous participions non pas tant pour l'ambiance mais surtout pour les opportunités.

La tournure avec « que » donne à mon sens plus d'importance à la partie après « non pas tant ».

> Nous participions non pas tant pour l'ambiance que pour les opportunités.

Merci à Chop pour son aide:
Ce que je veux dire avec la formulation "donne à mon sens plus d'importance", c'est que j'ai l'impression que la tournure avec "mais surtout" donne une importance de 10% au premier élément et de 90% au deuxième alors que la tournure avec "que" donne une importance de 30% au premier et de 70% au deuxième.
Les pourcentages sont juste une comparaison pour illustrer ma formulation mais je cherche justement à savoir s'il y a une telle différence entre les deux formulations (qu'elle soit de 20% comme dans mon exemple ou seulement de 1%).

Comment: Ainsi que [le dit Circeus](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14759/7224), même si ces tournures créent une certaine emphase sur le premier élément, elles signifient bien toutes les deux que le second groupe avait une importance supérieure.

Comment: @Chop. Ce que je voulais dire est que j'ai l'impression que la tournure avec "mais surtout" donne une importance de 10% au premier élément et de 90% au deuxième alors que la tournure avec "que" donne une importance de 30% au premier et de 70% au deuxième. Dans les deux cas le second groupe a une importance supérieur, mais ce qui m'importe est l'ordre de grandeur. ( les pourcentages sont juste une comparaison pour illustrer ma formulation "donne à mon sens plus d'importance")

Comment: Au temps pour moi. Il peut être intéressant de clarifier cela dans la question (l'écart d'importance entre les deux éléments est plus marqué dans le cas de la tournure avec _surtout_). La compréhension de chaque tournure dépend bien entendu du ressenti de chacun : certaines personnes ne verront que peu de différence entre les deux, d'autres auront la même perception que vous.

Comment: Je suis d’accord avec ce que vous dites, mais je vois peut-être une autre nuance entre les 2 : Avec «que» je vois la phrase comme une comparaison entre uniquement l’importance d’«ambiance» et celle d’«opportunités» (avec  «opportunités» qui gagne),mais est-ce que ça empêche forcement  qu’il y a d’autre raisons même plus important qu’«opportunités» ?  Avec «mais surtout» c’est clair qu’«opportunités» ne bat pas seulement «ambiance», mais tous les autres raisons possibles aussi: « … non pas tant pour l'ambiance que pour les opportunités, mais surtout pour la bouffe !»

Answer (score 3):

Il y a en effet une nuance, légère, qui sera plus audible que lisible : le fait de mettre plus de phonèmes dans une tournure que dans une autre indique bien que le le locuteur insiste, se donne la peine de sur-éclairer la chute de la phrase.

Autant Circeus a raison pour le sens exact, ils sont interchangeable, dans un contrat, dans une sentence judiciaire, le droit ne sera pas impacté.

En revanche, transposé dans une plaidoirie, l'intention des plaidants sera légèrement différente :

- avec *que*, c'est net, c'est dit, et la phrase suivante, normalement change de sujet, car c'est *quelque chose de normal* par rapport à la construction de la phrase qui a été exprimé, c'est une forme de conclusion ; on ne compare **que** deux éléments
- avec *mais surtout*,  c'est net, c'est dit, et la phrase suivante peut rebondir, ou attendre un silence prolongé, car c'est *quelque chose d'extraordinaire* qui a été exprimé, ce peut être une conclusion magistrale, ou une ouverture vers un développement en rebondissement ; il n'y a pas d'éventualités, de possibilités supérieures (*surtout = au-dessus de tout*).

Bien sûr, selon l'art oratoire des uns ou des autres, les intentions peuvent être exprimées en choisissant l'une ou l'autre formule, ce n'est pas une science exacte, mais, sans chiffrer en pourcentage, je rejoins votre interrogation et j'abonde dans votre sens.

Answer (score 2):

C'est une tournure parfaitement valide.

Toutefois, je ne crois pas (avis personnel) que l'une ou l'autre tournure donne plus d'importance au second élément. Leur formulation même met en exergue cet élément et lui donne donc automatiquement plus d'importance qu'au premier. Le sens même de l'expression, rejetant du revers de la main le premier élément pour donner l'ascendant au second, a le même effet.